# Entity Framework Table-Per-Type inheritance with overlapped (non-disjoint) entities

Tags: entity-framework, table-per-type

I'm using EF4 with DDD and layers, and I need to implement a Table-Per-Type hierarchy with non-disjoint (overlapped) entities in my data model, a model like [this](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-type-inheritance/). Anyway i cannot figure out how to do it, and cannot find any example of TPT with overlapped entities. There is any way  I can do this? (sorry for my english).